# Picturing ellipse plot $(x,y) = \left(\cos(\theta+\frac{d}{2}),\cos(\theta-\frac{d}{2})\right)$

Tags: r, correlation, covariance, linear-algebra, ellipse

The following paragraph taken from: [A Graphical Display of Large Correlation Matrices](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684435?origin=crossref)

[image]

I am trying to produce a plot with the provided equation above for the ellipse.

For example, given I have random and normally distributed data points:

```
data = np.array(np.random.normal(0, 1, 500)).reshape(100, 5)
outliers = np.array(np.random.uniform(5, 10, 25)).reshape(5, 5)
data = np.vstack((data, outliers))
```

I can get $\theta$:

```
theta = np.concatenate((np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 50), np.linspace(2*np.pi, -2*np.pi, 50)))
```

How do I get $d$ from the equation above? I have tried:

```
d = np.corrcoef(data[:,0], data[:,1])
np.array((np.cos(theta+d/2), np.sin(theta-d/2)))
```

However, $d$ is a $2x2$ matrix in this instance.

Comment: So, is your question about how to draw 'by hand' a single ellipse given two observed variables?

Comment: @utobi Hi! I want to figure out how to calculate for $d$ in the equation above. Because then I can just use `plt.plot(x,y)` to produce the ellipse.

Comment: see the updated answer with the full code. the short answer is $d = \cos^{-1}(\rho)$. Let me know if it is fine.

Comment: @utobi good catch, that would make sense. However, in my case I still get that $\rho$ is a $2x2$ matrix. How am I getting the single numerical value?

Comment: you have to pick the correlation between the two variables, right? then just take $\rho[1,2]$.

Comment: @utobi Ok! now that makes total sense, I completely missed out what the correlation matrix has to be interpreted like. Thank you!

Comment: glad to see it helped. Please, consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R` you can build these plots using the `corrplot` function from the homonymous package. Here is an example.

```
install.packages("corrplot")
library(corrplot)

corrplot(cor(mtcars), method = "ellipse", order="AOE")
```

[image]

The order of the variables in the plot is different from that in the dataset `mtcars` thanks to the option `order="AOE"`, which helps to have a nicer-looking plot.

The `corrplot` has a lot of options, so you might want to have a look at them,  e.g. `?corrplot`, to find those most suited to your needs.

**Update**
To draw a single ellipse "by hand", suppose $\rho=0.5$, then you can do as follows (the plot is also shown)

```
theta <- seq(0,2*pi, len=1000)
rho = 0.5
d = acos(rho)
x = cos(theta + d/2)
y = cos(theta - d/2)

plot(x,y, type="l", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I know and they also have a library named `ellipse`, however, I wanted to learn how to produce a simple version by "scratch". So I become familiar with the maths